# How to stop a function through another one in AS3?

Tags: flash, function, actionscript

So, i'm in this Flash CS5 file and i want to disable a function when another is running. To be more precise: i'm doing a function that makes me control a game character through keyboards. When this character hits another one, i want it to stop moving, even if i try to press the keys again. This is my code:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, move)
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, game)

function game(e:KeyboardEvent) : void {

if (e.keyCode == 39){
character.x += 15;
}

if (e.keyCode == 37){
character.x -= 15;
}

}

function game(e:Event): void {

if(character.hitTestObject(wall)) {

**how do i disable that move event here??**

}

}
```

I swear i've searched a lot! Hates to bother ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var canWalk:Boolean = true;

function game(e:KeyboardEvent) : void {

    if (e.keyCode == 39 && canWalk){
        character.x += 15;
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 37 && canWalk){
        character.x -= 15;
    }

}

function game(e:Event): void {

    if(character.hitTestObject(wall)) {
        canWalk = false; 
    }

}
```

You do have to switch it back to 'true' once the hitaction is over.

Comment: Thank you so much for que quick and clear reply, RST! I used your idea but i think since i'm using AS3 that "_root." part pointed to a error in my code, so i used a Boolean instead. That && part really saved me, thank you! ;)